# How to check the Google Play store app version

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying out the In-App Billing V3 from Google play. In the document below mentioned guidelines were given. I am not sure how to use the method isBillingSupported. Could you point me to any sample code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should view example project to clear anything.
<android-sdk>/extras\google\play_billing\samples\TrivialDrive

Comment: They have not used isBillingSupported in the TrivialDrive

Comment: you can see it in IabHelper class (line 236 )
int response = mService.isBillingSupported(3, packageName, ITEM_TYPE_INAPP);

Answer (score 1):

You can check the version of the GooglePlayStore app in your device like this:

```
PackageManager mPm = getPackageManager();
try{
    PackageInfo info = mPm.getPackageInfo("com.android.vending", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    int versionCode = info.versionCode;
    String versionName = info.versionName;
}
catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    // Play Store not installed
}
```

I don't know how to send the `isBillingSupported` request, but I found [this example on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/first087/9088162). I think it is what you are looking for.

Comment: But I need to go by there document to avoid any discrepancy. I am still looking for answers for the method isBillingSupported

Comment: Well, you asked "How to check the Google Play store app version" and that's what I answered, if you check the `versionName` you get the installed version (mine is 5.1.11) so you can just compare `String`s, and then you said "Could you point me to any sample code" and that's what I did jaja if you check line 73 of that code you can find a method that does what you want.